# How divide all items in an array by a double?

Tags: java

I am a complete beginner at this and I have a little problem with an array.
The point of this program is to calculate the normalization of a vector. The first part just calculates the length of the array into the int called sum and then I want to divide all the items in the array v with this sum. normal[] = v[a]/sum; this line is clearly the issue, but how should I do this??

```
public static double[] normalized(double[] v){

    double sum = 0;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < v.length; counter++){
        sum += Math.pow(v[counter], 2);
    }
        sum = Math.sqrt(sum);
        double[] normal;
    for(int a = 0; a < v.length; a++){      
        normal[] = v[a]/sum;
    }
return normal;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is specify an index for your normal array like so, and make sure to initialize normal:

```
double[] normal = new double[v.length];
for(int a = 0; a < v.length; a++)
{
  normal[a] = v[a]/sum;
}
```

Assuming that your sum is correct.  I believe this should work.

Comment: You could accept it as your answer then if you would like haha.

Comment: This isn't enough of an answer *on its own* as `normal` currently isn't initialized. Given that this is fixed by all the other answers, I'm not sure why this incomplete answer has the most upvotes at the moment...

Comment: That answer is wrong. normal is null. You need to initialize it first.

Comment: @Arpit: It's not even null - it's an uninitialized local variable. This will fail to *compile*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh yes! Silly mistake.I'ts indeed uninitialized reference. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet really, my for loop by itself won't compile?  Thank you master guru.  In my defense i did also include "and make sure to initialize normal" but i have added the code to make you all happy.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here I didn't know that there was such a thing as accepting an answer :P

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

- You're not initializing `normal` (or indeed creating an array to populate)
- You're not specifying which element you're trying to set within `normal`

So you want:

```
double[] normal = new double[v.length];
for(int a = 0; a < v.length; a++) {
  normal[a] = v[a] / sum;
}
return normal;
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet Anything that is tagged with Java or C# is your meal. Boy!!(admiration) how are you so good? Like how long have you been programming?

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra Jon,Java and c# are synonyms.

Comment: @Arpit Forget it. Jon wont reply. May be when I am 38(20 years from now) I will be having 596K reps :P

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra: Well I've been programming for about 30 years... but that's somewhat irrelevant :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 sum = Math.sqrt(sum);
  double[] normal=new double[v.length];
  for(int a = 0; a < v.length; a++){

      normal[a] = v[a]/sum;
  }
  return normal;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think below is what you need.

```
   double sum = 0;

   for(int counter = 0; counter < v.length; counter++){
   sum += Math.pow(v[counter], 2);
}
  sum = Math.sqrt(sum);
  double[] normal=new double[v.length];
  for(int a = 0; a < v.length; a++){

      normal[a] = v[a]/sum;
  }
  return normal;
```

Answer (score 2):

One-liner in Java 8:

```
double[] normal = DoubleStream.of(v).map(p->p/sum).toArray();
```